# Ngrx store value returned is true but trying to access it giving undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

**State value returns true or false according to reducer but could'nt able to access it as is undefined.**

here is my component code:

```
getState : Observable<any>;


   isAuthenticated : false;
      user = null;
      errorMessage = null;

  constructor( private store : Store<AppState>) {
    this.getState = this.store.select(selectAuthState);
   }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getState.subscribe((state)=>{
          this.isAuthenticated = state.isAuthenticated;
          this.user = state.user;
          this.errorMessage = state.errorMessage;           
        });
      }
```

state.ts code:

```
 export interface AppState{
        authState : auth.State;
    }
    
    export const reducers = {
        auth : auth.reducer
    }
    
    export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AppState>('auth');
```

reducer code :

```
export interface State{
    isAUthenticated : boolean;

    user : User | null;

    errorMessage : string | null;

}

export const initialState : State = {
    isAUthenticated : false,
    user : null,
    errorMessage : null
}


export function reducer (state = initialState, action : All) : State{
    switch(action.type){
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS : {
            return{
                ...state,
                isAUthenticated:true,
                user:{
                    token : action.payload.token,
                    email : action.payload.email
                },
                errorMessage : null
            };
        }
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE : {
            return{
                ...state, errorMessage : 'Incorrect email and/or password'
               
            };            
        } 
        case AuthActionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS :{
            return{
                isAUthenticated : true,
                user:{
                    token:action.payload.token,
                    email:action.payload.email
                },
                errorMessage: null
            };
        }
        case AuthActionTypes.SIGNUP_FAILURE : {
            return{
               ...state,
               errorMessage : 'That email is already in use.'
             };
        }
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGOUT : {
            return initialState;
        }

        case AuthActionTypes.RESET :{
            return initialState;
        }
        
        default : {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that state value returned is true but state.isAuthenticated is undefined. I even reviewed state values in redux devtools where the state value is changing accordingly.

[image: debug]

Comment: In `SIGNUP_SUCCESS` you are not spreading `...state` try add `...state` in your return

Comment: @KamranKhatti Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't solve the problem. As i have shown in my screenshot above i am able to get the state value but not able to access it using state.isAuthenticated. And i am able to access user object and errorMessage only problem is with the state.isAuthenticated value which is of type boolean.

Comment: Try console.log(state) and see wahts the response it will clear the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an typo "isAUthenticated" vs "isAuthenticated "

```
      case AuthActionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS :{
            return{
                isAUthenticated : true,
                user:{
                    token:action.payload.token,
                    email:action.payload.email
                },
                errorMessage: null
            };
        }
```

Also your debug message shows this typo

Comment: Thank you do much. I'm new into typescript and I overlooked that the error might be because of some interpretation with Boolean type and didn't concentrate on typo. Sorry about that

Comment: no issue. if you type the variable "getState" (Observable<State>) -> Typescript would have told you.